# How to free up Hardware Reserved RAM

Tags: windows-10, memory

I just got a stick of 8GB ram and added it to my build. I've searched around for a couple of hours and have tried many solutions in an attempt to free up the "Hardware Reserved" section in my Memory Usage. I think it may have to do with how my build is set up.

The motherboard I'm using is the GigaByte GA-990FXA-UD3 The RAM I've always had is [(2X4GB) CMZ8GX3M2A1600C9](https://www.corsair.com/ca/en/Categories/Products/Memory/High-Performance-Memory/Vengeance%C2%AE-%E2%80%94-8GB-Dual-Channel-DDR3-Memory-Kit/p/CMZ8GX3M2A1600C9). The one I just added is [F3-1600C11S-8GNT from G.Skill](https://www.gskill.com/product/165/186/1532583825/F3-1600C11S-8GNTValueDDR3-1600MHz-CL11-11-11-1.50V8GB-(1x8GB)). And for what it's worth, I'm running Windows 10 64-bit.

I've tried switching the "Boot" advanced option and unchecking the maximum memory usage in Systems Config. Another thing I tried was changing the `ClearPageFileAtShutDown` to a value of `1` in `Control -> Session Manager -> Memory Management`

I've also noticed that when I plug out one of the Corsair RAM sticks, the 4GB Reserved Hardware still existed (not sure what that meant but it kind of confused me). Without the new G.Skill RAM stick, the memory is as I would expect, 8GB.

It seems like there's an issue with the G.Skill RAM stick I bought.. Would anyone have any idea what is causing the Hardware Reserved Issue and how to fix it [or what it means?] Any help is appreciated; thanks!

Comment: 1. Are you sure that memory stick's original? Did you check it out first? Did you buy it from what shop? Tell us for helping you out.

Comment: I bought it from Canada's Computer (pretty reliable Canadian Computer branch) so I think it's safe to say it's the original?

Edit: here's the link to the product: https://www.canadacomputers.com/product_info.php?cPath=24_311_1904&item_id=063710&language=en

Comment: Double check that you're installing the new RAM in the right slot according to the manual.. Also, some motherboards require different placement when running on two sticks (1 stick might go in slot A1, but if you have 2, you might have to use slots A2 and B2 instead of just installing the new RAM in another slot)

Comment: Your first link sends us to a Corsair page for SoDIMM RAM, the other to a G.Skill page where you bought a RAM stick for a desktop, so I guess one of those two links is wrong, don't know which (I suspect it's the first, since you seem to have more than two RAM slots on your PC, but if you are the lucky owner of a high-end gaming PC like XMG or other, then I could be wrong). On-topic: is your BIOS set for dual-channel RAM? If so, your current setup accounts for two channels already, which means the additional RAM is set as "reserve". It's accessible and used, but only when your RAM maxes out.